# Is there a way to get the last chat massage in shout or say?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I want to search the last message for a few strings and then echo the message back with those strings replaced with other strings.

I searched multiple documentations but didn't find a way to get the last message.
This is the first forum I ask as I already have an account so have no real starting point to give you.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in the WoW API to get the last chat message of a specific channel. You will have to handle the [`CHAT_MSG_CHANNEL`](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Events/Communication#CHAT_MSG_CHANNEL) event (see [Event Handling](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Handling_events)) to read all messages, and store the newest one. Specifically for the say or yell (shout) channels there are the [`CHAT_MSG_SAY`](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Events/Communication#CHAT_MSG_SAY) and [`CHAT_MSG_YELL`](https://wowwiki.fandom.com/wiki/Events/Communication#CHAT_MSG_YELL) events respectively.

To do this your addon needs to own a Frame, these frames can register event handlers and you will have to store the last message you receive from that handler in a local variable in your script (let's call it `last_message`). Then when your other piece of code executes you can read the `last_message` variable:

```lua
local frame = CreateFrame("FRAME", "FooAddonFrame");
local last_message = nil;
frame:RegisterEvent("CHAT_MSG_CHANNEL");
local function eventHandler(self, event, ...)
 -- Look up the arguments that are given to your specific event
 -- and assign them to variables in order by retrieving them from
 -- the `...` variable arguments
 local msg, author, language, channel = ...
 print("Hello World! Hello " .. event);
 last_message = msg
end
frame:SetScript("OnEvent", eventHandler);
```

Comment: Personally I would always use [Ace3](https://www.wowace.com/projects/ace3) to develop addons, they provide many many many builtin tools for things like this.